# Ajax.Get Call not firing in Partial Views when master page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set a master page Employee Qualifications, this master page will include other views suck as work experience, employee skills, education.
In each partial view i have an ajax get method that brings the data and returns on success to render the partial view. the problem is that the method LoadWorkExperiences(); never gets fired when i navigate to the master page and hence the data is never loaded in view.

I am doing it this way because i want to open an edit popup window by clicking of the button. there for loading directly to master page is not my option.
Thanks for your help.

I tried calling "HumanResourse/WorkExperience/DisplayWorkExperience/15"  and it also does not fire the Ajax call.

the Master View cshtml HERE.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Areas/HumanResourse/Views/Shared/_LayoutHRUB.cshtml";
    int EmpId = ViewBag.EmployeeId;
}

<h2>Qualifications</h2>
<div>
    <p>Work Experience</p>
    @Html.Action("DisplayWorkExperience", "WorkExperience", new { id = EmpId })
</div>
<div>
    <p>Education</p>
    @Html.Action("DisplayEducation", "Education", new { id = EmpId })
</div>
```

the sub view code DisplayWorkExperience HERE.

```
@model SaaS.Areas.HumanResourse.Models.HR_Emp_WorkExperience_ViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>DisplayWorkExperience</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input class="hidden" id="EmpId" value="@ViewBag.EmployeeId" />

    <div class="container">
        <label>Work Experiences</label>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" onclick="AddNewWorkExperience(0)">Add New Work Experience</a> <br /><br />
        <table id="tblWorkExperience" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>


        @*Create A Popup Modal With Registration Form For Add Or Edit Student Record*@

        <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <h4 id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form">
                            <fieldset id="SubmitForm">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId, new { @id = "WorkExperienceId" })
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @id = "CompName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company Name*" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Position, new { @id = "Position", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Position*" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @id = "DateFrom", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @id = "DateTo", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment, new { @id = "Position", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Comment" })
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="SaveStudentRecord">Save</a>
                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>


@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(Document).ready(function () {
            $("#LoadingStatus").html("Loading....");

            LoadWorkExperiences();


        });

        //Start LoadWorkExperiences
        function LoadWorkExperiences() {
            $("#tblWorkExperience tbody tr").remove();
            var EmpId = $("#EmpId").val();
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpWorkExperiences", "WorkExperience", new {id = "ID"})'.replace("ID", EmpId),
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                               $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                   var rows = "<tr>"
                                       + "<td class='h5'>" + item.CompanyName + "</td>"
                                       + "<td class='h5'>" + item.Position + "</td>"
                                       + "<td class='h5'>" + item.From + "</td>"
                                       + "<td class='h5'>" + item.To + "</td>"
                                       + "<td class='h5'>" + item.Comment + "</td>"
                                       + "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditWorkExperience(" + item.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId + ")' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>" + "</td >"
                                       + "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteWorkExperience(" + item.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + "</td>"
                                       + "</tr>";

                                   $("#tblWorkExperience tbody").append(rows);
                                   $("#LoadingStatus").html(" ");
                               });
                           },
                 error: function (ex) {
                               var r = jQuery.parseJSON(Response.text);
                               alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                               alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                           }

            });
        };


    </script>
}
```

The Controller Code HERE.

```
 public class WorkExperienceController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext Db;

        public WorkExperienceController()
        {
            Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        // GET: HumanResourse/WorkExperience
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DisplayWorkExperience(int? id)
        {
            TempData["EmployeeId"] = id;
            ViewBag.EmployeeId = id;
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetEmpWorkExperiences(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Bad Request");
            }
            var EmpQualification = Db.HR_Emp_Qualifications.SingleOrDefault(p => p.HR_Emp_QualificationId == id);
            if (EmpQualification == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
            }
            List<HR_Emp_WorkExperience_ViewModel> EmpWorkExpList = EmpQualification.HR_Emp_WorkExperiences.Select(x => new HR_Emp_WorkExperience_ViewModel
            {
                HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId = x.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId,
                CompanyName = x.CompanyName,
                Position = x.Position,
                From = x.From,
                To = x.To,
                Comment = x.Comment
            }).ToList();
            return Json(EmpWorkExpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

i am getting now this error
Failed to construct 'Document': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: If you set the page's Layout to null, the `@section` sections will not be rendered. I'm not entirely getting what you're trying to do, here, since (as near as I can tell) you're going to wind up with some weird markup (your containing view is injecting a view with a full HTML document, which would be invalid).

Comment: i cant use @section in partial or in view without layout, then how i can load the data into that view using JQuery.

Comment: You might want to spend some time learning how the MVC framework works. See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc - that's for .NET Core, but the patterns are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rework what you have here, and it should work, like so:

#### Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Areas/HumanResourse/Views/Shared/_LayoutHRUB.cshtml";

    int EmpId = ViewBag.EmployeeId;
}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#LoadingStatus").html("Loading....");

            LoadWorkExperiences();
        });

        //Start LoadWorkExperiences
        function LoadWorkExperiences() {
            $("#tblWorkExperience tbody tr").remove();
            var EmpId = $("#EmpId").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpWorkExperiences", "WorkExperience")/' + EmpId,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            var rows = "<tr>"
                               + "<td class='h5'>" + item.CompanyName + "</td>"
                               + "<td class='h5'>" + item.Position + "</td>"
                               + "<td class='h5'>" + item.From + "</td>"
                               + "<td class='h5'>" + item.To + "</td>"
                               + "<td class='h5'>" + item.Comment + "</td>"
                               + "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditWorkExperience(" + item.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId + ")' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>" + "</td >"
                               + "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteWorkExperience(" + item.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + "</td>"
                               + "</tr>";

                            $("#tblWorkExperience tbody").append(rows);
                            $("#LoadingStatus").html(" ");
                       });
                   },
                error: function (ex) {
                   var r = jQuery.parseJSON(Response.text);
                   alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                   alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
               }

            });
        };
    </script>
}

<h2>Qualifications</h2>
<div>
    <p>Work Experience</p>
    @Html.Action("DisplayWorkExperience", "WorkExperience", new { id = EmpId })
</div>
<div>
    <p>Education</p>
    @Html.Action("DisplayEducation", "Education", new { id = EmpId })
</div>
```

#### DisplayWorkExperience.cshtml (displayed as a partial view):

```
<input class="hidden" id="EmpId" value="@ViewBag.EmployeeId" />

<div class="container">
    <label>Work Experiences</label>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" onclick="AddNewWorkExperience(0)">Add New Work Experience</a> <br /><br />
    <table id="tblWorkExperience" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    @*Create A Popup Modal With Registration Form For Add Or Edit Student Record*@

    <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4 id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="form">
                        <fieldset id="SubmitForm">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HR_Emp_WorkExperienceId, new { @id = "WorkExperienceId" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @id = "CompName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company Name*" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Position, new { @id = "Position", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Position*" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @id = "DateFrom", @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @id = "DateTo", @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment, new { @id = "Position", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Comment" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="SaveStudentRecord">Save</a>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a few changes to the controller:

```
public class WorkExperienceController : Controller
{
    // ... the rest of your code

    [ChildActionOnly] // An attribute which will prevent this action from being called by anything but Html.Action()
    public ActionResult DisplayWorkExperience(int? id)
    {
        TempData["EmployeeId"] = id;
        ViewBag.EmployeeId = id;

        return PartialView(); // this needs to return a partial view
    }

}
```

This is untested, but if I'm understanding the end result you're after, this should work. Basically:

1. Move the `@section` to the full view, Index.cshtml, so that it actually gets rendered. It doesn't matter where in the page you have that - I prefer to put @section calls at the top of the view, but it doesn't affect where that code is injected into the layout.
2. Change the return type of `DisplayWorkExperience` to `PartialViewResult`, so that it doesn't try to render the layout
3. Add the `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` to DisplayWorkExperience (optional) - this is purely to indicate that DisplayWorkExperience is only for rendering an embedded view, and will throw an exception if an attempt is made to navigate to that action.

From there, the jQuery code you have should work as I think you intended.

Comment: Thanks Tieson for your answer, but it didn't change anything, still unable to load and getting the same error.

Comment: I did modify your JavaScript a bit, so make sure that's updated - `Document` is likely a reserved word, and there's a more concise syntax that jQuery recommends anyway.

Comment: Thanks Man, that worked, i would never have thought to remove the (Document) word. i hope to get the popup working know. i will mark your answer as correct.